# How to Use Next.Js "Link" element as a custom React component with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I've tried to use "Link" element as my custom react component that I modified it with typescript to add some more facilities but everytime used it in my project it's made me to write a property with the name of props which its included some other properties :

below line is my typescript runtime error :

```
Type '{ link: string; title: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'DetailedReactHTMLElement<{ onMouseEnter?: MouseEventHandler<Element> | undefined; onClick?: MouseEventHandler<Element> | undefined; href?: string | undefined; ref?: any; }, HTMLElement>': type, ref, props, keyts(2739)
```

I wrote my custom react component :

```
import style from "./Button.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";
export const Button: React.FunctionComponent<
  React.DetailedReactHTMLElement<
    {
      onMouseEnter?: React.MouseEventHandler<Element> | undefined;
      onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler;
      href?: string | undefined;
      ref?: any;
    },
    HTMLElement
  > & {
    title?: string;
    link?: string;
  }
  > = ({ title, children, link, ...rest }) => (
  <Link href={`${link}`} {...rest}>
    {title ?? children}
  </Link>
  );
```

when I using it somewhere as my Button :

```
<Button link={exploreLink} title="Explore Event" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few points to note so you know what's going on...

- Your losing all Next/link attributes (`as`,
  `shallow`, `passHref`,`replace` , etc.)
- You are missing the required [anchor tag](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) inside of next/link
- Next link has its own type - `LinkProps`
- `link` as a prop name is confusing as the standard is `href` and it's already included
- `LinkProps` hold all standard next/link props;
- `FC` is react's built in functional component - adds `children` prop and sets return to a `ReactElement|null`
- `HTMLProps` are react's built in synthetic events and react specific props
- `HTMLAnchorElement` adds all standard html props like `className`, `title`, etc.

```js
import NextLink, { LinkProps } from 'next/link';
import { HTMLProps, FC } from 'react';

const LinkButton: FC<LinkProps & HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>> = ({
  as, children, href, replace, scroll, shallow, passHref, ...rest
}) => (
  <NextLink
    as={as}
    href={href}
    passHref={passHref}
    replace={replace}
    scroll={scroll}
    shallow={shallow}
  >
    <a {...rest}>
      {children}
    </a>
  </NextLink>
);
```

If your adding custom props you could make your own type

```js
import { MouseEvent, HTMLProps, FC } from 'react';

type MyLink = {
 customProp?: string;
} & LinkProps & HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>;

LinkButton: FC<MyLink> = ({ onClick, ...rest }) => {
 const customClick = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>)={
 }
 ....
}
```

Usage

```
<LinkButton href={exploreLink} title="Explore Event" />
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing respond , well I've changed my accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't need React.DetailedReactHTMLElement;
try:

```
React.FunctionComponent<
    {
      onMouseEnter?: React.MouseEventHandler<Element>;
      onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler;
      href?: string;
      ref?: any;
    }
  & {
    title?: string;
    link?: string;
  }
>
```

Comment: that's it
and for final question how about the className , how should I add this property to my custom button while there's not a property for add a class name to "Link" Next.Js

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/272